# Least amount of parts to switch a resistive load

Tags: resistance, mosfet-driver, nmos, sourcing

Excuse me for not being able to provide a schematic right now as I’m on mobile but my question is fairly straightforward.

I’m trying to drive a bunch of resistive loads fairly quickly in a constrained board space. For that reason I’m trying to minimize the amount of components that I need. Any suggestion that result in less components used is very much appreciated.

Objective: Drive an array of 16 x 30ohms resistive loads at 12V using a microcontroller as signal generator. The rise and fall time of the 12V over 30ohm load should be less than 150nS and the overall signal length is around 1.5uS. Also all the grounds of the resistor array is connected together. So in order to switch them individually I need to be able to control a high side switch. I’m currently using mosfet drivers with individual nmos with gate voltage at 24V, however I’m trying to minimize the amount of components I use so I need to find a sourcing driver array with the ability to source at least 400mA at high speeds but I can’t find anything.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Are you saying you'll add a schematic when you're on a PC instead of a mobile? The schematic editor here is a breeze to use. Again, welcome.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  You can use UDN2981 8-Channel Source Driver.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiplex simply the grid if you can afford to turn only 1 at a time (or 1 row).

You can also use MOSFET or BJT arrays like ULN2008. Check on Digikey.